# Indexing SQL-database slow down inserts too much

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have 2 queries taking too long time, timing out when running them inside an azure website.

1st.

```
SELECT Value FROM SEN.ValueTable WHERE OptId = @optId
```

2d

```
INSERT INTO SEN.ValueTable (Value, OptId) 
SELECT Value, OptId FROM REF.ValueTable WHERE OptId = @optId
```

The both SELECTS will always return 7860 Values. The problem is that I do around 10 of these queries with different @optId. First I ran without any Indexes, then the 1st Query would timeout every now and then. I then added a non-clustered index to SEN.ValueTable and then the 2d Query began to timeout.

1st Query from an Azure VM

2d Query from an Azure-WebApp

I've tried to increase the timeout-time through the .config-files, but they still timeout within 30seconds (There is no time limit from the customer, the retrieving of data from the sql-database will not be the slow thing of the application anyway).

Is there anyway to speed it up/get rid of the timeouts? Will indexing the REF.ValueTable speed the insert up anything?

Comment: Without you posting the execution plan, it's hard to assess why it's slow. The second query - inserting god knows how many values into an indexed table, might be slow because there are just god knows how many values.

If you have such large tables, consider table and index partitioning, or just executing partial queries (with the surrogate key % 4 =0, then 1, then 2, then 3. Thus having 3 queries and fewer timeout issues).

Comment: `The both SELECTS will always return 7860 Values. The problem is that I do around 10 of these queries with different @optId.` How do you do that?

Comment: Consider a clustered index on `OptId` on both tables, especially of the only 2 columns are `OptId` and `Value`.

Comment: Elaldas Buinauskas, you gave me the correct idea of what was wrong. What my problem was that I used `Dapper.QueryAsync`, which made too many queries at the same time. A better SQL-database might have handled this, but I'm running with 5 DTU's on Azure, which seems to be a bit too slow.

Answer (score 2):

If you really run such a query:

```
SELECT Value, OptId
FROM REF.ValueTable
WHERE OptId = @optId;
```

The best index for it would be the following:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ValueTable_OptId_Value
    ON REF.ValueTable (OptId)
    INCLUDE (Value);
```

Any index will slow inserts down, but will benefit read queries. If you want more elaborate answer, post more details - table DDLs and execution plans.

Comment: That was the kind of Index I've created, but UNCLUSTERED (not sure what is created if I don't specify the CLUSTERED/UNCLUSTERED). The problem was that the Inserts was too slow when I created that Index. The problem in the inserts was that I was trying to do them asynchronous, doing 10 of these inserts simultaneously, which in hindsight is kinda idiotic. Going away from `Dapper.QueryAsync` to `Dapper.Query` solved the issue (would work with an `await` infront of each `QueryAsync` too.) Thanks for your help though!

Comment: By default a nonclustered index is being created. :) and it's well known that indexes will slow inserts down, but benefit reads. It's a fair trade-off.

Answer (score 2):

First, the obvious solution is to add an index to `SEN.ValueTable(OptId, Value)` and to have no index on `REF.ValueTable(OptId, Value)`.  I think this gets around your performance problem.

More importantly, it should be not be taking 30 seconds to fetch or insert 7,860 rows -- nothing like that.  So, what else is going on?  Is there a trigger on `REF.ValueTable()` that might be slowing things down?  Are there other constraints?  Are the columns particularly wide?  I mean, if `Value` is `VARCHAR(MAX)` and normally 100 Mbytes, then inserting values might be an issue.

Comment: Value was a float, so it should've been OK. I'm running on slowest MsSql from Azure (5 DTU's), which probably was the reason SELECT's were slow. Indexing fixed the issue with slow SELECT's though, but then the INSERT's into SEN.ValueTable got too slow. That was because of me trying to do the INSERT's asynchronous with Dapper. The problem got solved with removing asynchronous calls when doing those inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Try resumable online index rebuild -
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resumable-online-index-rebuild-is-in-public-preview-for-azure-sql-db/

Comment: How would that solve the problem? Do you mean I should pause the indexing when inserting, and then resuming when I'm done with the inserts?